# .htaccess RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have a folder in my web root called docs and I need to ensure that files in this directory cannot be accessed by non authenticated users.

I have a file in this directory called index.php that verifies whether the user is logged in and serves up the requested file accordingly.

So in order to catch requests for files, in docs I have created the following .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?requested_file=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This works if I navigate to /docs/index.php then index.php is called. However if I navigate to /docs/cat.jpg then I am sent directly to cat.jpg. But I shouldn't be able to access this file...

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong here please?

Comment: Are you using `apache` or `nginx`?

Comment: I am using nginx locally and apache on the live server

Comment: Ok, but `.htaccess` is an Apache configuration file. It will have absolutely zero effect on your Nginx server.

Comment: Thanks Richard, however this isn't working on the server either

Comment: It doesn't sound like your `.htaccess` files is being processed at all. Remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper (you don't need it) - do you get an error? If not, try typing nonsense in the file - do you get an error?

Comment: Ok, so I created a new local server to test this, and set this up and it it indeed working as it should. Could you suggest any way I can debug why it isn't working this way on the live server?

Answer (score 2):

Well I tried your exact code on my Apache based stack and it works fine

**So There is nothing wrong with your apache instructions**

May be you are using php or IDE's inbuilt live servers. For that to work you need apache based stack like Lampp, Wampp, Xampp or Mampp.